# Back button to UIViewController from UITableVIew IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using xcode 4.4.1 using the IOS 5.1 simulator. I have started off with a View Controller that has 2 buttons. I have one button connected to a Table view that is embedded with a navigation controller. It is connected using a modal segue. When I run it in the simulator and click the button it goes to the table view but I don't have a button at the top to get back to the view controller. How do I make that button appear?

Comment: can you see the navigation controller in your tableview????

Comment: If it is presented as a modelviewcontroller, there wont be any back button. You might have to add a cancel or done button yourself and dismiss the model view on tap of that.

Comment: Back button automatically appear when you push view controller but when you present any view controller you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `UIBarButtonItem` and set it to the `navigationItem`'s `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem`, somewhat like the following:

```
UIBarButtonItem *closeBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self selector:@selector(closeTableView)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = closeBarButtonItem;
```

Then in the `closeTableView` method:

```
- (void)closeTableView
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```